# defining hash in tr1 for a template class

Tags: c++

I have the class Gateway.
I need to store object of this class in a hash table (using tr1::unordered_set).
I've used both the unorderd_set and the class Gateway in another context and they work fine, yet I can't figure how to put a gateway in a unordered set because I can't define its `hash` function in tr1's namespace.

I've tried: (and many other variants)

```
namespace std {
    namespace tr1 {
        template<> <typename T> inline size_t hash<(typename Gateway<T>)>::operator()(Gateway<T> gT) const {
            return gT.getCore()->hash();   //!DOESN't WORK
    }
}
```

The compiler says the this (`typename Gateway<T>`) is wrong. If i take the `()` off, it assumes the `>>` in the end of `hash<typename Gateway<T>>()` is the output stream.

While in the past i've done this

```
namespace std {
    namespace tr1 {
        template<> inline size_t hash<Board>::operator()(Board b) const {
            return b.hash();            //!WORKS FINE
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on the problem?

**Update**

Thanks for the answer yet there is still a problem The compiler says invalid use of incomplete type `struct std::tr1::hash<>`

This sort of error happens when we use the class without its complete definition, yet the class is fully defined before the declaration. I've already used this without templates in a very similar fashion without a problem.

Comment: `hash<typename Gateway<T>>()` you need a space between `>` characters. c++0x fixes this

Comment: I had a similar issue, following the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash saved me ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T> 
inline size_t hash<(typename Gateway<T>)>::operator()(Gateway<T> gT) const
```

Wrong syntax. `typename` is not required.

Correct syntax is this:

```
namespace tr1
{
    template <typename T> 
    inline size_t hash<Gateway<T> >::operator()(const Gateway<T> & gT) const 
    {
          return gT.getCore()->hash();          
    }
}
```

Notice I also made the parameter `const Gateway<T> &` type, just to avoid copy!

Also notice, the namespace `tr1` is not a nested namespace.